# How to optimize the perishable foods in the crashed plane

Tags: dead-in-bermuda

The food found in the crash site is a great source of food in the early game, but it's all perishable, so it should be used up fast. Also, it seems like the food perishes even when inside the plane. Or at least the quality of food found seems to go down as days go by.

What's a good strategy to optimize the use of the food found in the crashed plane? Starve people to make most out of Tasty Meals? Or balance them out with Meals? Should I take Barely Edible Stuff in account?

Also, does it make a difference if I rush getting all the items out of the plane, or if I decide to stall searching through it?